# MySQL and C++ program

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

I'm using the C connector library to establish connection with a MySQL database. When I include the linker and the other necessary components it runs fine, but once I compile it with an error, it denies me access of the debug folder. I've tried everything but somehow this folder has just become inaccessible and the executable has become inaccessible too

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you done, what errors do you get?

Comment: I solved it, the firewall was getting in the way of the program running smoothly but thank you so much!!!